# round decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use to round decimal in javascript like this:

```
lat = e.latLng.lat().toFixed(8);
```

works most of the times but some times I get more decimals as a result.

For example I get 8.341621100000001 from 8.341621100000001 that means that the number is not rounded. Issue is that I need to save it in the db with a 8 decimals precision and that this values are accepted by an API only with a 8 decimals precision.

How can I fix my code to have always it rounded to 8 decimals. We are talking about latitude and longitudes if it can help. Note that I know about issues with working with decimals in javascript but this seems to me like just an issue about using the wrong tool (sometimes it round sometimes it doesn't).

Thanks!

Comment: floating points numbers are _approximations_ or decimal numbers. They literally can't be used in this way. `toFixed(8)` will round to 8 significant digits _as close to the nearest floating point bitpattern it can_ and then gives you _that_ float value as a string, so the final step is to remember to use `substring()` before presenting it to the user or sending it to (a highly questionable) API

Comment: Why round? Im confused.... Just keep whatever precision you have.

Comment: If the API accepts floats it accepts floats. Im not seeing a string conversion @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: @GetSet don't mind why. It's just a requirement

Comment: Then @LelioFaieta where is your *problem*?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i'll go for splitting the string from the dot, trim the right part by 8 chars and combine it again

Comment: @GetSet did you read the question? Sometimes (like in the example) toFixed returns the input string with ALL the decimals and not with only 8

Comment: Why split and combine when string has built-in functions for substrings and finding character positions? `str.substring(0, str.indexOf(".") + 9)`

Comment: wow! you are true :-) thanks! place it as an answer for further reference if you don't mind!

Comment: That said, it's probably worth mentioning which API you're using because it's _entirely_ possible you misunderstood its documentation for the API call you're making and it supports floats perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment truncates the result and does *not* round it should be noted. Precision of rounding vs truncation is relevant for *decimal degrees*.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have tested it and it returns "Poorly formatted request" after 8 decimals. As mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @GetSet the rounding vs truncating difference here is not so relevant to have impacts in my specific situation

Comment: @LelioFaieta which is why I was confused. Do you want a float or a string? A float datatype will have those extra digits on some numbers no matter what you do. You could however round to a significant digit then convert to string.

Comment: @LelioFaieta please put that in your post to explain why it has to be 8 or fewer, then. That's the kind of detail that you should not leave out (and people should not have to find in a comment thread =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry but I don’t agree. Question is just how to round a decimal in js. The workaround is to trim and I have decided to apply it but the question is not how to round or trim, just how to round. Whatever the decimal represents

Comment: You will find that you're not disagreeing with me, but with [the Stackoverflow policy](/help/how-to-ask) around questions. Quite often, people ask questions about something they want to do, when the even better answer is one that solves the _underlying_ problem (e.g. in this case it could very well be calling an API in the wrong way by passing a string rather than pure numerical value). That might not be the case here, but putting those details in your post is _always_ worth doing, both for completeness, and to prevent an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395686).

Answer (score 0):

`.toFixed()` returns a String representing a rounded number, not a Number. As soon as you continue to use the value like a Number again (thanks to JavaScript's lax conversion rules), you re-enter the realm of floating-point inaccuracy.

If the API accepts strings for the numbers, then just call `.toFixed(8)` where you pass the value to the API.

Comment: this would lead to the same issue. I'll go for handling it as a string (after it is rounded it is placed in a input field) and trim it to 8 chars (digits) after the dot

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.toFixed()` then send the result through `parseFloat()`:

```
parseFloat(8.341621100000001.toFixed(8)); // 8.3416211
```

Or define a helped function to do it for you:

```
function clip(value, precision) {
    return parseFloat(value.toFixed(precision));
};

clip(8.341621100000001, 8); // 8.3416211
```